# Strange Situation While Working With Team Blox TreeView

Tags: android, treeview

I have been working with Team Blox TreeView for about 3 month now with no issues, but after the update from 0.1.0 to (0.1.1 or 0.1.2), I have experienced the following strange situation. I have tried to reproduce the situation I have been experiencing using the code below:

1) TreeViewTest.class:--------------

```
public class TreeViewTest extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "TreeViewTest";

private DrawerLayout dl_treeview_out;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
private FrameLayout fl_treeview_out;
private TreeView treev_treeview_out;
private BaseTreeAdapter adapter_out;
private TreeView treev_treeview_in;
private BaseTreeAdapter adapter_in;
private TextView tv_treeview_in;
private Button b_treeview_in;
private View inView;
private TreeNode mCurrentNodeOut;
private TreeNode mCurrentNodeIn;
private List<String> items;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.treeview_out);

    items = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0 ; i<=10 ; i++){
        if(i == 0) {
            items.add(i, "A" + "_" + "B");
        }else{
            items.add(i, "A" + i + "_" + "B" + i);
        }
    }

    // Out View -------------------------------- START

    dl_treeview_out = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.dl_treeview_out);

    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, dl_treeview_out , R.string.open, R.string.close) {

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };

    try {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG , " " , e);
    }

    treev_treeview_out = (TreeView) dl_treeview_out.findViewById(R.id.treev_treeview_out);

    treev_treeview_out.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            mCurrentNodeOut = adapter_out.getNode(i);

            if(mCurrentNodeOut.getData().toString().contains("A")){

                fl_treeview_out.removeAllViews();
                fl_treeview_out.addView(inView);

                tv_treeview_in.setText("In View");
                b_treeview_in.setText("~");

                TreeNode inNode = new TreeNode("B");
                adapter_in.setRootNode(inNode);


                dl_treeview_out.openDrawer(Gravity.START , true);
            }

        }
    });


    adapter_out = new BaseTreeAdapter<ViewHolderOut>(TreeViewTest.this, R.layout.treeview_out_node) {
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ViewHolderOut onCreateViewHolder(View view) {
            return new ViewHolderOut(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolderOut viewHolder, Object data, int position) {
            viewHolder.tv_out.setText(data.toString());
        }
    };

    treev_treeview_out.setAdapter(adapter_out);

    TreeNode outNode  = new TreeNode("A");
    adapter_out.setRootNode(outNode);

    fl_treeview_out = (FrameLayout) dl_treeview_out.findViewById(R.id.fl_treeview_out);

    // Out View -------------------------------- END



    // In View -------------------------------- START

    inView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.treeview_in , null);

    treev_treeview_in = (TreeView) inView.findViewById(R.id.treev_treeview_in);
    treev_treeview_in.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            mCurrentNodeIn = adapter_in.getNode(i);

            if(mCurrentNodeIn.getData().toString().contains("B")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "Data In: " + mCurrentNodeIn.getData().toString() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });

    adapter_in = new BaseTreeAdapter<ViewHolderIn>(TreeViewTest.this, R.layout.treeview_in_node) {
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ViewHolderIn onCreateViewHolder(View view) {
            return new ViewHolderIn(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolderIn viewHolder, Object data, int position) {
            viewHolder.tv_in.setText(data.toString());
        }
    };

    treev_treeview_in.setAdapter(adapter_in);

    tv_treeview_in = (TextView) inView.findViewById(R.id.tv_treeview_in);

    b_treeview_in = (Button) inView.findViewById(R.id.b_treeview_in);
    b_treeview_in.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            makeSelectListDialog("Select", TreeViewTest.this, items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    try {
                        String[] data_split = items.get(i).split("_");
                    if(data_split.length == 2){
                        if(data_split[0].contains("A") && data_split[1].contains("B")){
                            mCurrentNodeOut.setData(data_split[0]);
                            adapter_in.getNode(0).setData(data_split[1]);
                            adapter_in.notifyDataChanged(adapter_in.getNode(0));
                            adapter_out.notifyDataChanged(mCurrentNodeOut);
                        }
                    }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                }
            }).show();

        }
    });

    // In View -------------------------------- END


}

private class ViewHolderOut {
    CardView cv_out;
    TextView tv_out;

    ViewHolderOut(View view) {
        cv_out = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.cv_out);
        tv_out = (TextView) cv_out.findViewById(R.id.tv_out);
    }
}

private class ViewHolderIn {
    CardView cv_in;
    TextView tv_in;

    ViewHolderIn(View view) {
        cv_in = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.cv_in);
        tv_in = (TextView) cv_in.findViewById(R.id.tv_in);
    }
}

public static <T> AlertDialog makeSelectListDialog(String prompt,
                                                   Context finalContext, List<T> listItems, final DialogInterface.OnClickListener onYesListener,
                                                   final DialogInterface.OnClickListener onNoListener) {
    final ArrayAdapter<T> adapt =
            new ArrayAdapter<T>(finalContext, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, listItems);
    AlertDialog a = new AlertDialog.Builder(finalContext)
            .setTitle(prompt)
            .setAdapter(adapt, onYesListener)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", onNoListener)
            .create();

    return a;
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }else {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    drawerToggle.syncState();
}
}
```

2) treeview_out.xml:--------------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/dl_treeview_out"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff">

    <de.blox.treeview.TreeView
        android:id="@+id/treev_treeview_out"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:useMaxSize="true"
        app:lineColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:id="@+id/fl_treeview_out">

</FrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

3) treeview_out_node.xml:---------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/cv_out"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
card_view:cardElevation="18dp"
card_view:contentPadding="11dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_out"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="?attr/colorAccent"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

4) treeview_in.xml:----------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="100"
android:id="@+id/ll_treeview_in"
android:layout_gravity="start">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/b_treeview_in"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:id="@+id/tv_treeview_in"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2.5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="2.5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2.5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2.5dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/b_treeview_in"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="90"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#fff">

    <de.blox.treeview.TreeView
        android:id="@+id/treev_treeview_in"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:levelSeparation="20dp"
        app:lineColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

5) treeview_in_node.xml:-------------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/cv_in"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
card_view:cardElevation="18dp"
card_view:contentPadding="11dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_in"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="?attr/colorAccent"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

6) In the code above, I have created two TreeViews (**one directly inside activity and another one inside a drawer in this activity**) with one block each. **First TreeView block contains data starting with A (A , A1 , A2 , ...), where as Second TreeView block contains data starting with B (B , B1 , B2 , ...).** The idea here is that I'm trying to **change the data of first TreeView block and second TreeView block at the same time** by clicking a button from inside the drawer (**b_treeview_in**) and selecting data from a list which opens. The above code works properly (data of both TreeView blocks is getting updated) in version 0.1.0 of this library, but not working properly (First TreeView block data is getting updated, but the second TreeView block data is not) after the update to version (0.1.1 or 0.1.2). Note: In both cases if I check the data, I find that it changed to what was selected from the list, but visually in case of the second TreeView block it didn't change to what was selected.

7) If this problem is caused by `notifyDataChanged()` or `adapter.getNode()`, then why is it working for the first TreeView block?

8)

- In case of version 0.1.0
  [image: 0.1.0]
- In case of version 0.1.1 or 0.1.2
  [image: 0.1.1 or 0.1.2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Developer of TreeView here!

Unfortunatly this issues was causes by the library. I uploaded a new Version, which should fix it. Please try it out.

Comment: This fixed the problem. Thank you

Comment: I am trying to use treeview in a project. How to provide different layouts for parent and child nodes (define more than 1 type of node xml). Can you provide some example/tips?

Comment: @JunaidHamza The newer versions of the library are based on `RecyclerView`, so you have to create different view types for each layout. There are many tutorials on the internet for this.